# Tomcat fails to stop thread in webapp

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

In my webapp I have 3 threads where tomcat fails to stop 2 of these on reload.

> SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   mai 08, 2013 11:22:40 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads

This causes the CPU usage to rise for each reload.

Here is one of the threads that tomcat fails to stop:

Some of the code implemented in my ServletContextListener:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    final UpdaterThread updaterThread = new UpdaterThread();
    updaterThread.start();
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("updaterthread", updaterThread);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    UpdaterThread updaterThread = (UpdaterThread) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("updaterthread");
    if (updaterThread != null)
    {
        updaterThread.stopUpdater();
        updaterThread.interrupt();
        updaterThread = null;
    }
}
```

And the important parts of UpdaterThread:

```
public class UpdaterThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
    private boolean alive = true;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                while (alive)
                {
                    doUpdate();
                    sleep(60*1000);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    public void stopUpdater()
    {
        alive = false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this thread don't stops? Is there a better way to implement a thread doing some work at specific times?

Comment: Why do you have both `while(true)` and `while(alive)`? Even if you set `alive` to false, it would loop endlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're not actually stopping your thread at all. You have two `while` loops, and you only stop the inner when you set `alive = false`. The outer will run forever, doing nothing. You also don't handle the `interrupt` your sending, so that won't terminate the thread either.

I would instead do something like this:

```
public void run()
{
    while(alive)
    {
        try
        {
            doUpdate();
            sleep(60*1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            alive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you give your thread a proper name when creating it, you'll see if it's actually that thread that is causing the problem Tomcat is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

**it’s related to ThreadLocal issues with tomcat,** Check this document
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

> Mar 16, 2010 11:47:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearThreadLocalMap SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal
>   with key of type [test.MyThreadLocal] (value
>   [test.MyThreadLocal@4dbb9a58]) and a value of type [test.MyCounter]
>   (value [test.MyCounter@57922f46]) but failed to remove it when the web
>   application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has
>   been forcibly removed.

[http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84202-Installation-ThreadLocal-forcefully-removed](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection)

Answer (score 0):

A Small change in your code to fix this issue

```
public class UpdaterThread extends Thread implements Runnable
{
private boolean alive = true;

@Override
public void run()
{
    while(alive)
    {
        try
        {
            doUpdate();
            sleep(60*1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          //sleep interrupted
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          // exception in doUpdate method ? must handle this
        }
    }
}

 public void stopUpdater()
 {
    alive = false;
 }
}
```

However, `Sleep` in while loop likely to create a performance issue. You could use `Thread.sleep` only if you want to suspend your thread for some time. Do not use it if you want to wait for some condition.

**Check this SO question :** [Thread-sleep-called-in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535754/netbeans-java-new-hint-thread-sleep-called-in-loop)